# Pegar uma variável qualquer de um array que tenha certo id em AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array, filtro, id

Com o seguinte código, estou dizendo que no segundo array contido no objeto `$scope.listademercadoria` há a propriedade "quantidade", e estou declarando ela como valor 0.

```
$scope.listademercadoria[1].quantidade = 0;
```

existe uma forma de selecionar somente o array que contenha certo id como propriedade?

Ex: `$scope.listademercadoria[id = 2].quantidade = 0;`
Se funcionasse, pegaria somente os arrays que contém id=2 e setaria a quantidade para 0.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso sem o uso do `$filter`? Se não, como ficaria com o `$filter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem filter:

```
var filtrado = $scope.listademercadoria(function(item) {
  return item.id === 2;
})[0];
```

Com `$filter`:

```
var filtrado = $filter('filter')($scope.listademercadoria, {id: 2})[0];
```

Depois você usa o atributo que quer:

```
filtrado.quantidade = 0;
```

Comment: Em que momento ele seta a propriedade 'quantidade', paralela ao 'id', para 0?

Comment: @GuilhermeSilvadeOliveira no exemplo em lugar nenhum, agora é só você pegar a variável `fitlrado` e manipular como quiser.

Answer (score 1):

Usando apenas JavaScript (ES5):

```
$scope.listademercadoria.filter(function(i){ return i.id == 2; });
```

[Fonte.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)